# Display Products on Homepage From Custom Module

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I created one custom back-end module and admin can add products id in the back-end with comma separated , so how can I display that products on home page which is admin add in the back-end.

Here is my `productlisting.phtml` file

```
$collection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
        echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($collection1);
        echo "</pre>";
        $collection = Mage::getModel('productlisting/productlisting')->getCollection();
        foreach($collection as $date_to){
            if($date_to == $collection1)
        //  print_r($date_to->getProductId());
                $date_to->getLimit();
            //  print_r ($date_to->getLimit());
    //  var_dump($date_to->getProductId());
            echo "<br>";
            //print_r($date_to->getDateTo());
        }
```

Comment: Are you using cms/page to manage home page content?

Comment: no i am using xml layout file

Answer (score 1):

**A. First create your own Module on "local" code pool.**

This module will contains product collection with your own conditions.

For example,

```
class Mymodule_Myblock_Block_Product_Category_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    protected function _getCollection()
    {
        /** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->_categoryId));

        // filter by visible and status
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

        $collection->load();

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

You can add some own conditions or filter for product collection.

**B. Go to Admin panel, CMS > Page > Edit Home Page > Content.**

Add below code to call out the block.

```
{{block type="mymodule_myblock/product_category_list" template="mymodule/myblock/product/list.phtml" categoryId="1" title="New Products"}}
```

Also, you need to go to Permission > Blocks to add block name for white list.

*** This is just a simple example, you can add more different parameters to block/product collection to achieve your own Module more user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cms/page to modify homepage content

- You can search for how to create widget in magento. (to do show product you wish)
- In cms/page,you edit homepage. At content tab you insert the widget to homepage via wysiwyg panel